# Avoiding a NullPointerException when the user enters invalid data

Tags: java

How can I avoid a `NullPointerException` here if the user passes a null value for a date? Ideally, I would use a simple if statement.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String layupDate = dateFormatter.format(orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate());  
String layupTime = timeFormatter.format(orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate());
if(layupDate == null) {
}
```

Comment: you do a null check.

Comment: You need to check `orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate()` for `null` not `layupDate`

Comment: The gold-plated solution would be to have your `getLayupDate()` return an `Optional<LocalDateTime>` so you could use `orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate().ifPresent(ldt -> { /* do your formatting stuff here */ });` (or depending on situation and requirements, an `Optional<Instant>` or `Optional<ZonedDateTime>`).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

You validate the date (`orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate()`) in a liner (just creating a new date if null here but you can do as you please);

```
(orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate() == null) ? new Date() : orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate()
```

You can also go the traditional

```
if (orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate() == null) {
   orderLayupDateSet.setLayupDate(new Date());
}
```

Or you can do it the other way around with a utility, and calling the utility function to check for you - seeing that you return a String in your example above. Like the below;

```
public class DateUtils {
    public static String formatDateTime(Date dateOrNull) {
        return (dateOrNull == null ? null : DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(dateOrNull));
    }
}
```

Which in your code can be

```
String layupDate = (orderLayupDateSet == null || orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate() ? null : dateFormatter.format(orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate()));
```

Comment: just want to prevent this " String layupDate = dateFormatter.format(orderLayupDateSet.getLayupDate());   "  code from running if user enters null for date during test, I  want to allow null value.

Comment: I updated my example, in that case you would rather update your code and call a utility function that checks for you @TIM

Comment: I just need to put the logic inside if statement to allow null value when user passes it, if user passes the date then i need it to work